# angular-ui-router $stateChangeStart Event Not Firing in Angular Webpack ES2015 Component Build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, components, webpack

I'm trying to implement frontend JWT authentication in angular, but the $stateChangeStart event is not firing between states.  I'm using a component based architecture written in es2015 and bundled together with Webpack.

When I switch between states, the $stateChangeStart listener, set up in the run block, does not fire.

app.js is the entry point into the app.  I'm including other angular modules as components.

```js
import 'normalize.css';
import {appDirective} from './app.directive';

// Angular Dependencies
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';

// JWT Dependencies
import angularJwt from 'angular-jwt';
import angularStorage from 'angular-storage';

// Import shared services
import {services} from './services/services';

// Import components
import {signup} from './components/signup/signup';
import {login} from './components/login/login';
import {dashboard} from './components/dashboard/dashboard';

angular.module('app', [
  uiRouter,
  ngAnimate,
  angularJwt,
  angularStorage,

services.name,

signup.name,
login.name,
dashboard.name

])
.directive('app', appDirective)

// config $httpInterceptors to attach JWT tokens

.run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, to){
    // Check for authentication, but function does not execute
  });
});
```

Here's an example of a components' entry point file.  I set up the state for each component in these files.

```
import {dashboardDirective} from './dashboard.directive';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

export const dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', [uiRouter])
  .config(($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      template: '<dashboard></dashboard>',
      authenticate: true
    });
  })
  .directive('dashboard', dashboardDirective);
```

Using the .run block on the main app module to set up the listener for state changes works fine with other app architectures, but I cannot seem to understand why it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

This should trigger `$stateChangeStart` listener to run.

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  template: '<dashboard></dashboard>',
  authenticate: true,
  resolve: {
    data: function($q) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the state change events you have to rebuild the library with stateEvents.ts included. They are deprecated and it is better to use the functions. There is some syntactic sugar to make this easy.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '^/home/',
    onStart: ['$transition', '$state', function( transition, state){
    //your handling of this event
    });
```

Your post was in TS, so hopefully you can translate that. You can learn more about how to take advantage of the state lifecycle [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onenter)